# React library test, тестирование declare typescipt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]кто знает как протестировать declare переменную, как можно ее замокать в react-library-test, тест знает, что такое DEV? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]